# Letsencrypt: possible to register certificate for test.www.domain.com?

Tags: subdomain, lets-encrypt

Registering certificate for domain.com including several subdomains. Except for one sub-subdomain, all domains, subdomains and sub-subdomains are added to the certificate.

Only error that keeps coming back is for domain *test.www.domain.com*

*domain.com* -> works

*www.domain.com* -> works

*test.xyz.domain.com* -> works

*test.www.domain.com* -> **does not work**

A webpage is running on the domain *http://test.www.domain.com* and perfectly reachable on Port 80. Also pinging to this specific URL provides a correct response.

Hence, my question is there a way to add the full-domain *test.www.domain.com* to the certificate, or is this test.www somehow an invalid URL?

Detailed Error Message from Certbot:

> Failed authorization procedure. test.www.domain.com (http-01):
>   urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the
>   client to verify the domain :: DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA
>   for test.www.domain.com

Comment: Thanks for the -1, would appreciate the explanation. For now worked around this by skipping the www-subdomain when running the test-site version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That has become a well known issue recently.
As the error message states, there is a misconfiguration on DNS side:

```
DNS problem: SERVFAIL looking up CAA for test.www.domain.com
```

`CAA` (Certification Authority Authorization) record is intended to allow domain name owner to define which certificate authorities can issue certificates for this particular domain name. It is relatively new type of DNS record, and some DNS providers still failing to implement it properly, however it is mandatory for publicly trusted certificate authorities to support `CAA`.

The issue will not occur if `CAA` record is properly implemented, or not implemented at all.
But when DNS lookup for `CAA` record returns `SERVFAIL` status, Let's Encrypt will refuse to validate the domain name.

Here is the corresponding [announcement from Let's Encrypt](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/caa-servfail-changes/38298):

---

When originally implementing CAA, we ran into a number of issues with various DNS providers not properly supporting queries for this record type. Because of this we implemented a soft-fail behavior when DNS servers return the SERVFAIL error code to CAA queries instead of the expected NOERRROR code.

Over the last year and a half, we’ve worked with a number of these providers to move towards spec compliance, but there are still a few misconfigured providers. However, we are moving towards strict enforcement of CAA, where SERVFAIL responses will block issuance. This is also in line with upcoming industry requirements: all CAs will soon be required to check CAA by the [CA/Browser Forum Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/).